# Replacing SD card by using EEPROM

Tags: sd, eeprom, mbed

I am using the mbed platform and to be specific, NUCLEO L073RZ. To log data, I am using `SDFileSystem.cpp` that is officially supported by mbed (you can find the link [here](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/mbed/code/SDFileSystem/)).

Now using an SD card in an industrial setting is not really good, but I need to use the same library so that I will not have to change my code a lot. What are the criteria that I need to look into for EEPROM to make sure that a particular model resembles an SD card as close as possible?

Comment: why? there are industrial grade sd card and emmc if you are worried about temperature and contact

Comment: Yes, I am aware of industrial grade sd card but our vendors are facing supply chain problem so we will not be able to get the quantity that we wanted. My constraint is that I need to find EEPROM that closely resembles SD file system provided by mbed.

Another problem that we are facing is the need to reduce read/write access time. There is a significant penalty of using SD card.

Comment: "There is a significant penalty of using SD card." - a good SD card can write at several Megabytes per second. What data rate and access time do you need, and what capacity?

Comment: I'm not aware of any EEPROM drivers which have a similar implementation as SDFileSystem. How many files, and which size are we talking about? Shouldn't be too hard to swap out SD card IO for EEPROM IO given that you often just get a flat address space, can do anything with it.